# How to update Target (right click properties) of an .exe using a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to update the Target of an .exe using my batch file. Is it possible? 
Basically, i would like to make my app auto-login by adding userid and password to it and i don't want to manually do this for every installation that i do.

So from Target: C:\Softwarebin\Software.exe  to   Target: "C:\Softwarebin\Software.exe -user:app -passwd: app1"

At the moment, i have to do this manually everytime i install our software for the users by right clicking the desktop shortcut and editing the Target field as above. It would be great to have a batch command which i could include in my install.bat file which would update this for me as well after the installation is complete.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks
irish

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the target of the .exe itself, however, you can make\modify a shortcut with vbscript and run it from a batch-file the following way:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set prog_shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut("Your_shortcut_location\Shortcut.lnk")
prog_shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Softwarebin\Software.exe -user:app -passwd: app1"
prog_shortcut.Save
```

Notice that CreateShortcut also modify an existing shortcut, so it should do the trick.

You can run the vbscript from command afterwards if you need.

Comment: Thanks Shperb, i have just tried this and i have got the following error:   "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Set Auto Login For Rapper\SetAutoLogin.vbs(3, 1)
 Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: It could be due to this line of script:
Set prog_shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Rapper.lnk").... Is this correct?

I am running it using a bat file: 
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
cscript SetAutoLogin.vbs

Comment: I tested the script, it worked for me, can you copy the full code you are using?

Comment: Here is the full code: 
Thanks


Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set prog_shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Rapper.lnk")
prog_shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Rapper\bin\Rapper.exe -user:app -passwd: app1"
prog_shortcut.Save

Comment: Sorry i am completely alien to VB scripting so pardon me if i haven't used the syntax correctly.

Thanks

Comment: The syntax seems fine, is it a copy-paste of the code? (no typographical error with the variables name?) and is there a new line after each line of the code?
I tested the script myself just now and it works fine.

Comment: It is a copy paste of the code. There is a new line after each line of the code. Hmm weird, do i need to set some sort of environment variable path? I am definitely missing something silly here.... would it overwrite an already existing shortcut?

Comment: The error code is 800A0005, Char 3 line 1... Spelling looks alright to me.

Comment: Is this line 3? prog_shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Rapper\bin\Rapper.exe -user:app -passwd: app1" if so,is "prog_shortcut" and "TargetPath" spelled correctly?

Comment: any other suggestion?